# Mother and Daughter

Tags: calculation-puzzle, number-theory

A mother (not yet a centenarian) and her daughter (who happens to share her mother's birthday) are both a prime number of years old. Moreover, in their lifetimes there have been at least a dozen other times at which both of their ages have been prime. How old are they?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

We are looking for

> a number (the difference of their ages) that is at least, let's say, 12, and that is the difference of two primes below 100 in at least 13 ways.

The only way I know of to find one is

> brute force. I told my computer how to do it, and it tells me that 12 and 30 are both differences of two primes below 100 in exactly 13 ways, and that nothing else manages so many. It is not surprising that these are numbers with lots of small factors, since e.g. if p is a prime >5 then at any rate p+30 will not be a multiple of any of {2,3,5} which is a good start :-).

I think

> a 12-year difference is very unlikely, though not quite impossible, so let's go with 30. The relevant ages are: 7,37; 11,41; 13,43; 17,47; 23,53; 29,59; 31,61; 37,67; 41,71; 43,73; 53,83; 59,89; 67,97.

So

> the mother is 97 and the daughter 67.

Comment: what about when the baby is 1? With your solution, the mother would be a prime age then also...

Comment: 1 is not a prime number.

Comment: Why choose that specific combo?

Comment: Because, as I explained in the answer, there are only two possibilities: that one and another that would require the mother to have become a mother implausibly young.

Comment: They may also have both been prime ages when the mother was 31 and the daughter was 2.

Comment: Yes, but we can ignore that possibility because then the difference in ages is odd and you're going to have a world of pain trying to find *more* prime-number age differences.

Answer (score 7):

<sup>(Appended with a surprise solution courtesy of
 [Jonathan
  Allan](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/16717/jonathan-allan).)</sup>

A visual approach reveals a likely age difference of...

> ...30 years
>  with the ages of mother and daughter being **97** and **67**...

...as seen in this extract from the diagram that follows its recipe below.

> ```
>                3.5.7..1113..1719..23....2931....37..4143..47....53....5961....67
>                   37..4143..47....53....5961....67..7173....79..83....89......97
>  28 ------\    3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |
>  30 ------/        |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
>                    1   2 3   4     5     6 7     8   9 10        11    12      13
> ```

The diagram displays how primes line up when staggered.
 
**Recipe:**

1. Space the list of primes up to 100 on a number line
   and convert them to `|` bars.
2. Make a rudimentary text edit macro that copies the previous two lines
   and shifts them two spaces right and left
   while also pruning now-overhanging characters.
    
   This produces a triangular array where each successive line is
   shifted from the previous by two more spaces each time.
   (No need for odd shifts as
   all primes in question will be odd and thus only have even differences.)
3. Defocus slightly and look for a disruption in scatteredness,
   an area of regularity where many `|`s stack up in pairs.
4. Sure enough, there was that regularity, on the lines marked.
    
   (Hmm, it doesn’t quite leap out
   when displayed here like it did on my editor.)
    
   Other pairs of lines also have much regularity,
   especially among smaller age differences,
   but the immediately apparent instance satisfied the puzzle.

```
  3.5.7..1113..1719..23....2931....37..4143..47....53....5961....67..7173....79..83....89......97
  | | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
2 5 |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
4   3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |
6    11 |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
8     3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |
10   13   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
12      3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |
14     17 |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
16        3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |
18         23     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
20          3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |
22              | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
24            3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |
26           29 |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
28 ------\    3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |
30 ------/        |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
32                3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |
34               37   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
36                  3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |
38                 41 |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
40                    3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |
42                     47     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
44                      3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |
46                          |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
48                        3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |
50                       53     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
52                          3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |
54                           39 |     |   | |     |   |     |       |
56                            3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   |
58                           61     |   | |     |   |     |       |
60                              3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |
62                               67   | |     |   |     |       |
64                                3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |
66                                 71 |     |   |     |       |
68                                  3 | |   | |   | |   |     |
70                                 73     |   |     |       |
72                                    3 | |   | |   | |   |
74                                     79   |     |       |
76                                      3 | |   | |   | |
78                                       83     |       |
80                                        3 | |   | |   |
82                                            |       |
84                                          3 | |   | |
86                                         89       |
88                                            3 | |
90                                                |
92                                              3 |
94                                             97
```

**Surprise:**

Loosely allowing for adoption and/or remarriage,
mother’s and daughter’s ages
could be much closer or in the opposite order, so
[Jonathan Allan went and found](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/55116/mother-and-daughter/55118#comment169837_55118),...

> ...by extending the number line past 100,
>  a solution where mother is **97** (again),
>  daughter is **103**(!) with
>  an age difference of 6 years,
>  and this is the 16th(!!) time their ages are both prime.
>
> ```
>    3.5.7..1113..1719..23....2931....37..4143..47....53....5961....67..7173....79..83....89......97...103
>    .1113..1719..23....2931....37..4143..47....53....5961....67..7173....79..83....89......97...103
>  4 3 | |   | |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |     |
>  6  11 |   | |   |     | |     |   | |   |     |     | |     |   | |     |   |     |       |     |
>      1 2   3 4   5     6       7     8   9     10    11     12     13    14        15           16
> ```

Comment: How do you adopt someone who is older than you? They'd be an adult! Remarriage makes sense, though it would basically require a 20 year old to marry a 70 year old in order for the daughter to be 30 years older.

Comment: Anything is possible, at least in a song: [I'm My Own Grandpa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%27m_My_Own_Grandpa)

Comment: @Braydon but the daughter only needs to be six years older (daughter, mother): `(11, 5), (13, 7), (17, 11), (19, 13), (23, 17), (29, 23), (37, 31), (43, 37), (47, 41), (53, 47), (59, 53), (67, 61), (73, 67), (79, 73), (89, 83), (103, 97)` (note daughter is, at the 16th occurrence, a centenarian, but mother is not yet).

Comment: What a catch, @Jonathan Allan, you should post that!  My flip closing comment completely neglected the centenarian aspect anyway.

Comment: Oh ...not to neglect an age gap of zero of course!

Comment: So true, @Jonathan Aha-llan, they could even have been born twins . .

Comment: No rush to post your find, @Jonathan Allan, though if you're not interested would you mind if I added it here with attribution?

Comment: Certainly add it - I don't think it's worthy of a whole answer :D

Answer (score 1):

Skipping the ages 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37
because both mother and daughter have had a dozen prime number ages.

Ages of (mother, daughter) are as follows:
(59, 41);
(61, 41);
(67, 41);
(71, 41);
(73, 41);
(79, 41);
(61, 43);
(67, 43);
(71, 43);
(73, 43);
(79, 43);
(83, 43);
(67, 47);
(71, 47);
(73, 47);
(79, 47);
(83, 47);
(71, 53);
(73, 53);
(79, 53);
(83, 53);
(89, 53);
(79, 59);
(83, 59);
(89, 59);
(97, 59);
(79, 61);
(83, 61);
(89, 61);
(97, 61);
(89, 67);
(97, 67);
(89, 71);
(97, 71);
(97, 73); and
(97, 79).

There were 36 solutions allowing for an age delta of [18, 40].

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**)  I'm not sure I even know what your answer to the puzzle *is*, let alone know why you think your answer provides a solution to the puzzle. Could you please explain why you believe this is the answer? Answers without explanation are generally deleted.  In addition, I'm not sure how your answer adds to the solutions already given and Accepted. You should always look at existing answers before providing one of your own, to ensure you are not just adding a duplicate.

Comment: There are at least twelve times their ages are both prime *at the same time*.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE:** my original answer is not valid anymore since the OP changed the question a bit.

Assuming her mother lived until $100$ years old and it is known that at least <strike>12</strike>$13$ times the age difference would be the same:

> There are four possible ages for the mother and her daughter: <strike>(97,79), (97,73), (89,59)</strike> and $(97,67)$.

Here are the ages for their life time if the difference was $18$:

```
1-)  23 5
2-)  29 11
3-)  31 13
4-)  37 19
5-)  41 23
6-)  47 29
7-)  59 41
8-)  61 43
9-)  71 53
10-) 79 61
11-) 89 71
12-) 97 79
```

if the difference was $24$:

```
1-)  29 5
2-)  31 7
3-)  37 13
4-)  41 17
5-)  43 19
6-)  47 23
7-)  53 29
8-)  61 37
9-)  67 43
10-) 71 47
11-) 83 59
12-) 97 73
```

and if the difference was $30$:

```
1-)  37 7
2-)  41 11
3-)  43 13
4-)  47 17
5-)  53 23
6-)  59 29
7-)  61 31
8-)  67 37
9-)  71 41
10-) 73 43
11-) 83 53
12-) 89 59
13-) 97 67
```

So since it is given that "**have been at least a dozen <strike>of</strike> *other* times**" there are <strike>4</strike>$1$ possible answer<strike>s</strike> assuming they cannot age more than $100$ years old.

**FYI:** Surprisingly if they can age more, the next possible age differences becomes $36$,$42$,$48$ and so on, which are all the multiples of $6$.

Comment: Excellent reading of the puzzle, Oray, and very interesting multiples-of-6 observation(!), which seems to extend down to **12** and **6** (and 0, -6, ...) as well

Comment: Argh, I was just about to argue that this is the most complete solution but then the puzzle statement was revised to require "at least a dozen ***other*** times...." **This still stands out as the most interesting solution.**

Comment: @humn just noticed that too. I will edit accordingly. But OP should put a word for the maximum age limit as well in my opinion.